# Time conflict in dual boot system

Tags: time

As per the suggestion by one of my friends, I tried to follow the process to edit `/etc/default/rcS` and then changed `UTC=no` but after this I'm not able to save this.

Can any tell the solution.

Comment: use the -- sudo -- command in front and then it will save. It will help if you also update the question with the versions of you dual boot system plus what do you mean by time conflict you get, for examples minutes, hours, days etc

Comment: If using gedit or a graphical based editor use gksudo or gksu not sudo. It may cause issues to use sudo with gui based apps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too dual booting between linux and windows because windows likes to override the time with the time it *thinks* it should be. You need to disable UTC time in linux, which it looks like you tried, but you need to do so as root, because this is in the /etc directory which is owned by root. Just put `sudo` in front of whatever command you were using to do this